# Node JS Express MySQL , can not get all users

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I can't get all users, but if write manually it works.

```
class User {

static getAll(result) {
        let sql = `SELECT * FROM users`;

        sql.query(sql, (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log("error: ", err);
                result(null, err);
                return;
            }

            console.log("users: ", res);
            result(null, res);
        });
    }

}

exports.findAll = (req, res) => {
    User.getAll = (err, data) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send({ message: err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving users." });
        res.send(data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*query()* is a method of a mysql connection, you are using it as a string method:

```
let sql = 'SELECT * FROM users';
sql.query()
```

You should first create the connection with your database, and then use that connection object to make your queries, something like this:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "yourusername",
  password: "yourpassword",
  database: "mydb"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  con.query("SELECT * FROM users", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

Comment: mysql connection are in seperate file, now problem is, if i using GET method is not working/sending request always loading to long.